# Animating sliding left/right when showing/hiding in AngularJS / ngAnimate

Tags: javascript, angularjs, animation

I have 3 sections (divs) - we'll call them `#section1` to `#section3`. When the page loads, `#section1` is the only one of the three visible owing to ngShow - I have a variable `visibleSection` in the controller that's a value of either `1`, `2` or `3` to determine which is visible.

I have a JSFiddle here that's set up with those conditions.
https://jsfiddle.net/46x01Ldm/14/

However, what I'm looking for is a way to make the sections move when you click "Next" or "Previous".

When the user clicks "Previous", I'd like the old section to slide out to the right and the new section to slide in from the left, as if the user has swiped to the right with their finger.

When the user clicks "Next", I'd like the old section to slide out to the *left* and the new section to slide in from the *right*, as if the user has swiped to the *left* with their finger.

How would I go about achieving this?

Thank you very much for any suggestions or assistance! I have jQuery and animate.css to work with, if that helps.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given that you're using animate.css, just give the section that needs to move out one of the exit classes (Like `bounceOutLeft`) and the class you'd like to move in one of the entrance classes (Like `bounceInRight`).

Along with that, to keep track of which section the user is looking at, I'd have a variable that's keeping track of which section the user is looking at. I'd add 1 to the variable when the user presses the next button and the opposite with the previous button. Then just animate the the children you need based on this variable.